# How to get dynamic pdf file from database in React and Node

Tags: reactjs, node.js, database, postgresql, express

I built a physical assessment application. The user types the patient's measurements into the form and submits. After this, a pdf is generated with a table and some calculations regarding the values ​​submitted and the user is redirected to the main page. In the "Acompanhe suas avaliações" menu, I want it to open a new tab when the user clicks with the data submitted in the previous form. I have already configured the database for this. The problem I'm facing is that I can't save the generated PDF in the database, I can only get a "BLOB" format link, but this link is temporary and expires after closing the tab. Please help me, I'm going crazy.

I tried @react-pdf/renderer, however I need to save the image to the database, and it only provides the temporary "BLOB" link.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be good if you included how that PDF is created, perhaps post a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you generate the PDF somehow client-side and create a Object URL for it
(what you call "temporary BLOB link"), and now the question is how to send it to server for storage in PostgreSQL?

To get the data of an Object URL you can download it just the same way you would any other file. I.e. using `fetch`:

```
const res = await fetch(blobUrl)
const myBlob = await res.blob()
```

Then, to send it to the server, you would make a second request like  this:

```
await fetch(`/my/pdf/upload`, {
  method: `POST`,
  body: myBlob
})
```

All that being said, I think it would be more suitable to generate the PDF server side. Would save you some headache.